# How do I add a navigation item that is a link to another domain in fuelCMS 1.4?

Tags: fuelcms

How do I add a navigation item that is a link to another domain in fuelCMS 1.4?

When I am logged in as an admin and I create a navigation item. There doesn't appear to be any way to simply enter an absolute link as the location.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this:

Although the note on the location field states "Enter the path of url after the domain name.",  if you enter the full url it will work too.  Just make sure to enter the key field with the url that matches your menu items location in the menu.